# Locate File IDs of contentVersion and attachment objects that contain a specific word within them

Tags: attachment, contentversion

The need is to compile a list of fileIDs of 2 types of Salesforce files that contain a specific word within them.

- Document Files in ContentVersion
- Email Attachment files in Attachment

When using global search to search in FILES, an elegant list of matching files are returned (but without the file ID )

The goal is exclude these files/delete them prior to migrating to a new org.

It seems that the only option is to do 2 passes:
Use Data Loader to search ContentVersion object, download the file using curl and then check if the word is present

Rinse and Repeat for Attachment object.

Is there a more elegant solution to somehow get to the file ID of these files so we can exclude them easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of values using SOSL, such as:

```
FIND {word} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ContentVersion(Id, ContentDocumentId), Attachment
```

This would return a list of up to 2,000 rows of content version and/or attachment and the relevant ContentDocumentId so you can delete/exclude the records. Of course, you may want to review the data before deleting it, but this query should help narrow down your search (pun intended).

I'm not sure if the Data Loader can actually do SOSL, but there are plenty of tools out there that can.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, this searches within the attached binary file too ( blobs) i.e. attached .pdf, .docx, .pptx. .xlsx. files in addition to text fields. Now all I need to do is to apply some kind of date range to work within the constraint of 2000 rows (actually workbench stops at 1000 rows).... by specifying some intelligent way to read row 1001 to 2000, then 2001 to 3000 etc...Expecting some 5K records.

Comment: Removing Attachment  from the list of returned values makes workbench return 2000 rows

FIND {<mySearchString>} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ContentVersion(Id, ContentDocumentId)


Still have to figure out how to make the thing work for up to 4000-6000 expected hits

Comment: @EashwerB.Iyer you can do progressive searches by adding a WHERE clause to each RETURNING to filter by, for example, Id or CreatedDate so you can find all the values. This is easy in Apex.

Comment: It seems SOSL on workbench also lets me set a where clause. Let me check.
- How do I bulk download these files?
- As regards deletion, now that I have the fileIDs , I can mass delete them from DocumentVersion using any tool like process builder , workbench, etc

Comment: @EashwerB.Iyer Oh, I meant you could do it programmatically in Apex, so long as it's less than 10k files. For workbench, there should be a download CSV option.

Comment: We need to do it in APEX. I tried estimating the number by file type/file extension. SOSL on workbench is whimsical - it showed me up to 2K .pdf files (as there are more than 2K of them) but returned no records with the docx and doc extension even through there are quite a few of them visible without any filter specified. Duh..
Filters in SOSL are goofy.
I guess there is only programmatic retrieval left for us to try w/APEX.

Comment: @EashwerB.Iyer SOSL has a 2k limit across all returned types. You could balance it with `RETURNING ContentDocument(WHERE ... LIMIT 1000), Attachment(WHERE ... LIMIT 1000)`. This would give you the proper estimates in any tool that supports SOSL, but I'd say it'll still be easiest in Apex.

Comment: @EashwerB.Iyer use something like `ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1000` for the first, then `WHERE ID > (the last id from previous batch) ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1000`. But it would be a lot faster in Apex anyways.

Comment: That worked well to estimate the number of files..... although the moment I had fewer than the number of files i specified as the limit, SOSL returns the number or records as the number by which I fell short of the limit exceeded the limit. Weird. But now I have triply confirmed the number of files on the list.

Thanks. Next step is to use data export to get all the file Ids out of the system.

Comment: I would like to include the PARENT ID (be it a case, account , opportunity record to which the file is attached). I'm looking at a ContentVersion ID and ContentDocumentId in ContentVersion record. On the SF/UI I can see that it is a html attachment....and i want to know what object it is connected to (parent id)... on the SF/UI i am able to see it is a case.But i am getting a null parent id in contentDocument object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EashwerB.Iyer a single document can be attached to many records. You'll have to query the Content document link table with the content document id values to get that info. Parent id on content document actually refers to a Folder/Library, whatever they're calling it these days. Check out the docs on Content Version. It has all the related data you need.